# How to get <div> to extend horizontally beyond page (or Iframe) boundary without specifying width

Tags: css, iframe

So I have a web page that displays some of its content within a 600px wide iframe. The wrapper  for the UI within the iframe is 500px wide with overflow set to be hidden. Within this UI is a  containing a single row of photographs arranged horizontally. Different users will have different numbers of photographs so there cannot be a width specified. In most cases the, width of all photographs (and their margins) will exceed the 500px wide UI so not all of them will be visible at once. The user will be able to drag and scroll this  horizontally in order to see the photos that are not in view when the page loads.

```css
.wrap {
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.scroller-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
}
.scroller {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
.scroller img {
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="scroller-container">
        <div class="scroller">
            <img src="myimg.png" /><img src="myimg.png" /><img src="myimg.png" /><img src="myimg.png" /><img src="myimg.png" /><img src="myimg.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that since there is only 100px between the right edge of the wrapper  and the right edge of the , the scroller  is only extending that 100px before it "wraps" the photos onto a 2nd line and expands its height vertically because it has reached the right edge of the . In order for the photos to scroll horizontally, they must remain all in 1 row.

If I was able to specify a fixed width for the scroller , it would extend beyond the boundary of the  and remain in 1 row and everything would be great. But since the width will be different on a user to user basis, that's not possible.

Is there a CSS-only way to get that non-fixed-width  to beyond the right boundary of the `<iframe>`?

Comment: I tried white-space: no wrap to no avail. As soon as it runs out of space in the iframe, it stops expanding horizontally and wraps the remaining content to the next line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap` to the `.scroller`. This will (i) prevent the images from breaking into newline (ii) expand the div horizontally past 100% width if necessary.

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/cuxv5gLs/)

Comment: Will that work with .scroller being assigned to a <ul> and the images each as their own <LI> (floated left or display: inline-block) or does it have to be <div>s? Im wondering if the float will cause any complications??

Comment: There is no harm in experimenting :) Having said that, `white-space: nowrap` does not work with floats. You can use `white-space: nowrap; list-style: none` on ul and `display: inline-block` on li.